# How to pass an entire view in ContextMenu?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, contextmenu, commandparameter

I am using context menu on a datagrid for copy/paste. But I am not getting my current view in ContextMenu's Command Parameter.In other command bindings I have passed my View name as Command parameter to get the current view status. But now I am stuck with this ContextMenu as I am not able to pass my view through it. I am using MVVM.

My snippet is

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu x:Name="_menu">
           <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" 
           CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext}" />
      </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way (in my opinion) is to declare your `ViewModel` as a static resource within your page. Then you can bind your root panel's `DataContext` to this static resource (getting you to where you are now). This then has the added benefit of making the binding work in your `CommandParameter` (by binding the parameter to a `StaticResource` rather than using `FindAncestor`).

The most probable reason why your current Binding expression isnt working is that your hit a template encapsulation boundary, but I cant be sure without seeing all of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu x:Name="_menu">
           <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" 
           CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}},Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" />
      </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

i assume that your datagrid is in your current view

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried this also but the problem is that the datagrid contains values which are defined in other ViewModel which is not its( the Views) DataContext. I have select rows from the datagrid,right-click and copy. I want the selected item from the views object which I am not able to retrieve as the object gets set to null.

Comment: an easy way would be to expose the windowviewmodel as a property of the datagridview viewmodel. but if you do so, you can get rid of the commandparameter, because you have to windowviemwodel in your currentviewmodel. so i would say get rid of the commandparameter and inject the windowviewmodel to your datagridviewmodel via mef or what ever.